# React Native Project Running from Xcode but not from command line

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native

I'm hitting a production breaking bug and the solution seems elusive, but tantalisingly close.

That odd thing is, the app runs on the simulator if I run from Xcode (With the play button), but when I run **react-native run-ios** it brings up the simulator and shows the splash screen, but then immediately fails out, with little to go on in the logs.  I suspect something is not getting included when the app is run from command line that is included when run from xcode.

Can anyone with a better understanding of ios dev suggest any pointers?

Comment: What does "fails out" mean? Does the app display a white screen? Crash? Red error page?

Comment: Crashes.  I get the 'app powered by react-native' screen, then immediate crash.  No red error page at all.  No logs either as far as I can tell.

Comment: did you manage to sovle this?

Comment: In such cases, I used to open targeted simulator before running the command, in most of the case I use iPhone 6s simulator. Sometime react native app breaks if your default simulator is set to something higher than iPhone6s

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Open Info.plist with notepad (not XCode) and look for errors. If you don't find any, try restarting XCode or your mac and do a clean build.